# Unable to understand jsp syntax

Tags: jsp

```
<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html"%>
 <%@ page import="MyClasses.*"%>
 <html><head><title>Switch the log ON</title></head><body>
 <%
 **MyLog log = (MyLog)application.getAttribute("logFile");**
 if (log == null) {
 try {
 log = new MyLog(
```

I am new to Java and Jsp. I got the above lines from a doc. I am not able to understand the line in bold. Could someone please tell me what it looks like a typecast ?

Comment: Post your all code in jsp file.

Answer (score 1):

Takes the logFile object (MyLog) and assigns it to log, if the object is empty it goes on to instantiate a new object. I'd read up on Object Oriented Programming basics first.

Comment: Yes I should be and I am reading a core java parallel. In which section can I see the above sort of declaration please ?

Comment: You could try reading this [link](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/jsp/jsp-application-object-methods.html). 

Though if you are reading a book, perhaps you don't need to understand that at where you are currently at. Perhaps the author only wants you to get a first taste with explanations coming up in later chapters.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I understand the application object and its methods which is shared by all the objects.

Comment: application.getAttribute("logfile") will get me the value of the attribute logFile, if I had setAttribute before or else null. In this case the first time, it evaluates to null and then it is set to an object of class MyLog. which means after this whenever I do get attribute, I get the object itself.. Is my understanding correct ?
(MyFile) is for typecasting ?

Comment: Yeah you get the MyLog object if it's been instantiated. If not then the code instantiates a new one, from what I can see anyway. And yes it is for that. Sorry, didn't understand that you meant just the (MyLog) part of the syntax earlier.

Comment: Yes, and `application` is sort of an application-wide map. Meaning any .jsp file can assign to and read from it.

Comment: logFile is not an object. its a variable name of the value which is associated with it for access purpose. It can be anything like Object, primitive value...

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the examples of *lazy initialization* design pattern. Your example may be expressed with the following getter:

```
private String var;
public String getVar() {
    if(var == null) {
        var = "I was initialized lazily in a getter";
        return var;
    } else {
        return var;
    }
}
```

As you can see, `var` was initialized **only when it was accessed for the first time**: if it wasn't needed, it wouldn't be created at all. With this pattern you avoid creation of too many objects beforehand and create them only when they are demanded. When objects are quite heavy and many of the are used infrequently, this approach may significantly improve performance of your application under load.

That said, you'd be better off finding books/resources that don't advocate the usage of scriptlets in JSP, as it is considered a bad programming practice.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** JSP has many implicit objects and 1 of which is **application** object.

**2)** JSP's **application** object = servlet's **ServletContext** object (**getServletConfig().getServletContext()**).

**3)** These objects are used to access *web.xml* configuration information. And there is only **one** *ServletContext* or *application* object per web application.

**Your Code interpretation:**

`application.getAttribute("logFile")` is trying to find some object/value whose associated **key** string(variable) is *logFile* in the context.